# Servo starts to shake when I added SIM900.begin(19200);

Tags: servo, gsm, simulator, keypad

Hello I'm working on this mini project. This project works this way, Whenever someone type wrong password, LCD will display "Access Denied" and send an alert to SMS using GSM module.  I used 2 Arduinos for this project, The 1st Arduino is powered up by my laptop this is where the signal pins are connected the RX/TX of GSM is connected in (pin 10 and 11) respectively and the LCD is in pin (2-9) and Servo to (A4) . The second Arduino I used is powered up with a charger and used it for GSM power source it function well as it blinks every 2 sec. I'm really wondering why my servo is shaking whenever I add the  SIM900.begin(9600); at the setup in Arduino IDE?

This is the code

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Password.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(10, 11); 

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE); 
Password password = Password( "9999" );
Servo myservo;

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {'1','2','3','A'},
    {'4','5','6','B'},
    {'7','8','9','C'},
    {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {3, 4, 5, 6}; 
byte colPins[COLS] = {7, 8, 9, 10}; 

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
int pos = 0;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM900.begin(9600);

  myservo.attach(13); 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("Arduino Password");  
  lcd.setCursor ( 0, 1 );       
  lcd.print (" Door  Lock ");
  delay ( 2000 );
  setup1();

}
void setup1(){

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();
  lcd.print("Enter your code:");
  keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); 
}

void loop(){
  keypad.getKey();
}

//take care of some special events
void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent eKey){
  switch (keypad.getState()){
    case PRESSED:
        Serial.println(eKey);
        switch (eKey){
          case '4': checkPassword(); break;  
          case '2': password.reset(); break;
          case '8': lock(); break;
          default: password.append(eKey);
     }
  }
}

void checkPassword(){
  if (password.evaluate()){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Access granted");
    delay(1000);
    unlock();
  }else{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Access denied");
    delay(2000);
    sendSMS();
    delay(1000);


  }
  password.reset();
  delay(1000);
  setup1();
}

void unlock(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Unlocking...");
  delay(2000);
  pos = 90;
  myservo.write(pos);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Unlocked! Press");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("* to lock!");
  delay(1000);
}

void lock(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Locking...");
  delay(1000);
  pos = 0;
  myservo.write(pos);
  setup1();
}
void sendSMS() {

  SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
  delay(100);
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+6XXXXXXXXXX\""); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("Wrong password Typed"); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println((char)26); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println();
  // Give module time to send SMS
  delay(5000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Servo.h use interrupts to generate the control signal. However, SoftwareSerial really messes interrupts up.

You can't use SoftwareSerial with anything that relies on interrupts for timing, like Servo.h.

Solutions:

1. Use a better Arduino with an unused hardware UART
2. Use an external hardware PWM controller to drive the servos
3. Use the internal hardware PWM (you'd need to find a library to do this) to drive the servos.

Comment: You can't use SoftwareSerial with anything that uses Timer1.  You can use all the other interrupts that you want.

Comment: Is there any library available for gsm that won't messes interrupts? or can you  suggest a best article for the internal hardware PWM ?

Comment: @Delta_G SoftwareSerial disables interrupts when sending. It also blocks all interrupts while receiving. You can't sensibly use SoftwareSerial with *any* timer interrupts and have it do anything reliable.

Comment: @Chard You may get better luck with AltSoftSerial. I did see a hardware PWM library around once, but I can't recall where. Ask Google - she knows.

Comment: I tried to replace SoftwareSerial to AltSoftSerial but stil the servo is shaking.

Comment: Btw I'm using Arduino Uno

Comment: @Chard Get a more suitable board then - or an external PWM servo driver module.

Comment: So it means there's no possibility to work this project on Arduino Uno? why? is it because of the interrupt pins?

Comment: It is possible - it just isn't easy. You need a good understanding of the underlying hardware. The problem you have is lack of suitable hardware resources, so are having to use software emulation ("Bit Banging") to get around it. And that doesn't work well when you're trying to do other things as well.

Answer (score -1):

Both SoftwareSerial and Servo are trying to use the same hardware timer, Timer1.  There are other servo libraries like ServoTimer2 that will allow you to use SoftwareSerial and there are other soft serial libraries that will allow you to use Servo.  It is a pretty common topic that comes up a lot.  If you search a little bit you should find several solutions.

Comment: I used the #include"ServoTimer2.h" and remove the #include<Servo.h>. but the servo is still shaking.

Comment: SoftwareSerial does *not* use a timer.  It uses PCINT to trigger reception, and both reception and transmission of data use a "tuned delay" based on `_delay_loop_2` which is a hard blocking loop written in assembly (in delay_basic.h).